# Select2 type to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use select2 to have a multi-select dropdown list of states, but something is wrong.

Normally, when you type an option out, it's highlighted so that you can hit enter and select it. It underlines the option, but does not highlight it, so if I type "alabama" but hit enter, it will select "arkansas".

I'm using the latest version (3.5.1)

HTML

```
<label class="control-label" for="states">States:</label>
<input id="states" name="states" />
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit Search" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#states").select2({ 
    width: 'resolve',
    maximumSelectionSize: 5,
    ajax: {
        dataType:"json",
        url:"getStates.cfm",
        results: function(data) {
            return {results:data};
        }
    },
    multiple:true
});
```

Am I missing some sort of parameter? I could have sworn this was working fine the last time I used it. No console errors, and it click selects perfectly.

Note that the [github](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) page works just like I want (when you type, it selects the first option that matches)
[image]

Comment: It seems unlikely, but I wonder if, due to the lowercase 'a' at the beginning, the select2 algorithm really "thinks" that "Arkansas" is lexicographically closer to "alabama" than "Alabama" is.

Comment: @Retsam - I constructed a demo to test that theory, and that was not a cause of this situation.

Comment: Is there any reason why Arkansas is being returned when Alabama is being queried?

Comment: Arkansas is the first option. On the github page, by typing in the box, the most relevant option is highlighted. But not for mine. That is the issue here

Comment: How did you actually solved your problem? The accepted answer does not seems suitable. And the chat link is also 404 now. I am having the exact issue.

Comment: @codeofnode my condolences -- this issue plagued me for days before I found out: dynamically added JSON options will not trigger the autocomplete. The list  needs to be static (for some reason, I forget now) in order for it to autocomplete nicely.

Comment: my list is static.. It does not have any random order.. But still there is issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Select2 3.x, the highlighted result in the dropdown will always be the first result during searches.  This will be changing in Select2 4.x, so the selected option will be selected if it is present.

You are looking for the results to be sorted differently. By default, Select2 orders options by the order that they have within the DOM, not by how relevant they are. The documentation [provides an example](https://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#sort_results) of how to customize the sorting of results using the `sortResults` option.

Keep in mind that it is more efficient to sort the results on the server side when using AJAX, which is why Select2 does not do any further sorting. This would explain why "Arkansas" is being returned when searching for "Alabama".

Comment: I'm not quite following this answer, I don't want to sort my options

Comment: After re-reading, this is not relevant to my issue unfortunately. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Look at what my select2 is doing, then go to the github page, type in an option, and see what it does. Select2 is supposed to highlight the most relevant option when you type (aka the keyup/keypress events). I'm not looking for default highlighting. Please read my question again

Comment: False. Please, look at the github link. My results clearly match, but it's not highlighted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64056/discussion-between-kevin-brown-and-sterling-archer).

Comment: I am also looking for the solution of same. I am having exact problem as the question describes. Answer is accepted but i could not find anything relevant in sortResult. I do not want to sort, i just want to highlight the first one that is matched with Select2.util.markMatch. I am still on select2 3.x

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And solution was found when i found that every time i type into search box, each time it calls `query` function. That's it. So all i required to do fill results only if it matches at least one character in anyone of the text of the available options. The following way :

```
query  : function(opts){
  var res = [];
  var fulloptions = ArrayFoundUponYourAjaxOrAnyStaticOptions;
  var stripDiacritics = Select2.util.stripDiacritics;
  for(var z=0,len=fulloptions.length;z<len;z++){
    if(stripDiacritics(fulloptions[z].text.toUpperCase()).
        indexOf(stripDiacritics(opts.term.toUpperCase())) >= 0){
      res.push(fulloptions[z]);
    }
  }
  opts.callback({ results : res }); // res is your filtered/matching rows out of which first one will get auto hightlighted
}
```